# How to add data with puppeteer automatically to a page with for loop?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

In the code below I am trying to login to my website and add some data to it. When I add data only for once code works.

```
(async () => {

  //get the data from myFunction
  const ad_data = await myFunction();

  //login to my webpage
  let myUrl = 'https:blabla.com';
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await page.goto(myUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  await page.click('input[type=email]');
  await page.keyboard.type(C.username);
  await page.click('input[type=password]');
  await page.keyboard.type(C.password);
  await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
  
  await page.waitForNavigation('networkIdle2', 60000);

  //choose the value 'published' from dropdown menu
  await page.select('select#status-filter.column-filter', 'Published');

  // choose the company name from dropdown menu
  await page.select('select#company-filter.column-filter', 'f14dca75');

  // click the button to create a new job-ad page
  await page.click('a#create_new_link');

  // add job title here
  await page.type('input[name="Title"]', ad_data[0].title);

  // add job description here
  await page.type('#DescriptionJson_editor', ad_data[0].content); 

  //close the browser
  await browser.close();
})();
```

But I need to add more data so I use a for loop like this...

````
    ```
   ....
   await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
 for (let i = 0; i < ad_data.length; i++) {
   await page.waitForNavigation('networkIdle2', 60000);
   await page.select('select#status-filter.column-filter', 'Published');
   await page.select('select#company-filter.column-filter','f14dca75' );
   await page.click('a#create_new_link');
   
   // add job title here
   await page.type('input[name="Title"]', ad_data[i].title);
   ...
   ...
   }
   //close the browser after for loop
    await browser.close();
    })();
````

...and then the code just executes one time even though there is more data to be added. Can someone please help me through this?

Comment: I suspect it's because of `page.waitForNavigation` - which waits for the page to reload or to go to another URL.

Comment: Thanks @Vaviloff, your comment helped me to figure out the problem. I removed the await page.waitForNavigation() Inside for loop and added  await page.goto(myUrl) and it works now.